# jquery .load not working for this example

Tags: jquery

I have an empty table with cell's whose id's are already assigned

e.g.

```
<td id="se/sv-1">&nbsp</td>
```

Then I have a go button defined like so

```
<a href="#" alt="PreSurf" id="submit"><img src="go.png"></a>
```

In the bottom (important?) of the page but still within the body I have the following script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $("a#submit").click(function(event) {
        $("#se/sv-1").load("psurl.php?server=someserver.somehost.com&url=/se/sv&port=80");
    });
});
```

Yet it doesn't load on click... I have tested the url (obviously the hostname is changed to protect the innocent) and it works exactly like it should... I have tested by replacing the .load line with a simple alert('booya'); and it works yet the .load doesn't

Any ideas?

Comment: i would try to avoid slashes and other special chars in dom id's. it could be a problem, dunno how jquery deals with it...

Comment: @Marwelln It is allowed in HTML5. And jQuery will deal fine with it if correct escaping is used in the selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$("#se\\/sv-1")` instead of `$("#se/sv-1")`

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must
>   escape the character with two backslashes: \\.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: You got it in one - man I hate it when it's so simple. I hate it more when I had already done another correction for other id's that contained a . :) You will get your correct answer when the frankly ridiculous time limit is over in 9 minutes ... :)

Comment: The experience is the secret .. i had a doubt when i saw the `/` .. i tested my suggestion and wrote it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a forward slash in an ID. If you must remember to escape it.

```
$("se\\/sv-1")
```

Comment: you are right of course... it's messy but the value supplied from a php function. Think I will rewrite the function to remove the slashes as it will make no difference to the outcome.